# How To Get AccessToken From Orange Message Api

Tags: c#, orange-api

i need to know how to get an access token from  Orange Message Api . i wrote a function  that should to do this but it seem to contain a bug . it return an Exception 
[**The Remote Server Returned An errro 400 Bad Request**] .  i dont know what is go wrong

```
 class MessageApi
{

    public  void GetAccessToken()
    {
        string AuthHeader = "My Authorization header";
        HttpWebRequest requeust = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.orange.com/oauth/v2/token");
        requeust.ContentType = "application/json";
        requeust.Method = "POST";
        JsonObject JsonData = new JsonObject();
        JsonData["authorization"] = AuthHeader;
        JsonData["grant_type"] = "client_credentials";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(requeust.GetRequestStream()))
        {

            streamWriter.Write(JsonData);

        }
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)requeust.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Authorization header should be in the request header.

Instead of doing

```
JsonData["authorization"] = AuthHeader;
```

try

```
requeust.Headers["Authorization"] = AuthHeader;
```

Comment: it still throw the same exception

Comment: are you able to get an answer using curl like [here](https://developer.orange.com/support/technical-guides/2-Legged%20OAuth) ?

Comment: also add `streamWriter.Flush();` and `streamWriter.Close();` after the line `streamWriter.Write(JsonData);`

Comment: the same thing when i add  .flush()  , .close() ,methods . i will try to get answer using curl .

Answer (score 0):

**DO this first :**
The client_id and client_secret are used to specify the authorization_header.
Its value is composed of the keyword “Basic”, followed by a space and the base64 encoding of the concatenation of your client_id, “:” and your client_secret

You need to convert your in base64 your client_id:client_secret in this site : [base64 encode](https://www.base64encode.org/)

**example**:

client_id = djdv6+4fb64b+6fd+6b

client_secret = 3464ggb646

concated =  djdv6+4fb64b+6fd+6b:3464ggb646

djdv6+4fb64b+6fd+6b:3464ggb646 == d64b6b464b6g4bg65465gn6n==

**After Do this :**

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic myBase64Encode" -d "grant_type=client_credentials" https://api.orange.com/oauth/v2/token
```

replace myBase64Encode with your concatenated clientId and clientSecret converted in base 64 ==> d64b6b464b6g4bg65465gn6n==